# Orthogonal projection of a point on a line in 3D

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a point **A**( 3,2,0) on a plane 
$\alpha$ = 2x+y-z-8=0 
How to find the orthogonal projection of  point **A** on a line **r** that has a direction vector ( 1,1,1) passes through the origin ? And What are the coordinates of **A’** on **r**

Comment: How is the plane relevant?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You need to find $t$ such that with $A'=(t,t,t)$ we have $\vec{AA'} \perp \bf r$, that is $(3-t,\,2-t,\,-t)\cdot(1,1,1)=0$.

Comment: -3t+5=0 —> t=5/3 thank you so much

Comment: Do you see why $A'$ has to be in form $(t,t,t)$?

Comment: Because **A’** is a point on a line **r**, then it  has the components of a generic point ( x,y,z ) of **r**  which is ( x=t,y=t,z=t ) ?